# js: complex Regex replace freezes all script for seconds

Tags: javascript

When I do apply a regex on very big string, all my JS freezes for seconds.

Is there a way to run some asynchronous regex or functions to not block all the JS ?

Comment: Please share that regex and test cases that freeze the browser for seconds.

Comment: you could try to use a web worker

Comment: You want to do the `regex` in the `backend`. And `ajax` into it to do the work.

Comment: it is a BLOG image text (>500Kbytes).
So ajax is really bad solution. It freezes essentially Safari.